# Sanitizing Intent file URIs

Tags: android, android-intent, sanitization

I have an Android chat application, which accepts a large variety of possible sharing intents. I'm trying to harden the parsing logic for file URIs in my app. For example, URIs containing the package name of my app are filtered, since otherwise an external application could try and trick a user into sharing the entire database of messages with someone else. I also want to block attempts to read `/proc/self` and similar. I'm looking for a list of directories which should be blocked, or even better, a library which performs this sanitization for me. Another option would be to use a whitelist of external caches and directories, which I could get from the Android system. Can anyone give me advice on which option would be best? Or can anyone give me a list of similar directories to `proc` that should be blacklisted at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for closure's sake, I'll post the solution I went with. I block anything including `/proc/` and my application's package name, like so:

```
val path = uri.getPath
if (path.contains(context.getPackageName) || path.startsWith("/proc")) {
  None
} else {
  Some(u)
}
```

Note that when doing sanitization in general, you want to perform it as late as possible, after any other transformations, to reduce the risk of your step being bypassed.